# Calling into an AIR Native Extensions from an Actionscript Worker

Tags: air, flash-builder, air-native-extension

I'm currently trying to push off some time consuming tasks to an actionscript worker. This worker will in turn needs to call out to an AIR Native Extension as part of it's processing.

I've tried various combination in Flash Builder 4.7 i.e. embedded worker and external worker (with explicit packaging of the ANE in the external worker project)  but alas I've been unable to get this to setup to work. I keep getting an error from the worker saying that the native extesion class could not be found (Error #1014).

Does anyone know if it is at all possible to do this or it's a limitation of Actionscript workers?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this might be a bit late now, but I've just been having this problem myself, and it was caused by the ANE not being packaged with the app when it's sent to the device / simulator.

Classes within the NE weren't being found at runtime, but were accessible in Flash Builder.

It turned out that by default the .ANE file wasn't copied to the device.

To fix this, change the following project property:

*ActionScript Build Packaging -> Apple iOS -> Native Extensions -> **Check 'Package' for the ANE***

No idea why it wasn't included by default. When you uncheck 'Package' you get a warning telling you that it may cause runtime issues!

Hope this is of use for somebody.